# Where do you track the developments of new c++ standards?

Tags: c++, standards, c++11, specifications

Where do you guys generally look for developments in C++, most importantly, developments in new standard and its approx/scheduled release data? also boost (well, boost.com)

Is there a centralized place?

thx

Comment: It seams like C++0x has been taking forever!

Comment: The good news it will last [forever] too!

Comment: This is the problem with a language that ins't "developed" by anyone (like Microsoft & C#). It can take forever to get updated. Just look at Java.

Comment: Which makes it stable, and considering how widely used it is, is arguably a good thing.

Comment: @KTC: Oh it's stable, but look at how long it's been since the last update. I think it's something like 1998!??! If your using a framework like Qt, then it's easy to use, but if your using regular C++ and the WinAPI, it can really suck.

Comment: The long time since last update is (to some extent) intentional. They wanted to give the language time to stabilize, and ensure both compilers and users got time to catch up. We might have hoped for a C++0x in 2008 or maybe 2007, but I don't think it was ever the plan to deliver an update before that. So it's not *just* the delays, but also a conscious policy to give it time. Future updates should be much faster (Stroustrup has mentioned a 5-year cycle in the future)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ has been updated much here lately. I would recommend [wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) on C++ though. It usually is kept up to date (not that a lot's changed). I guess the closest thing to a specification that I've found is [Bjarne Stroustrup's book](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/glossary.html) (the creator of the C++ language) on, what else, the C++ language.

Comment: please don't forget to provide the link.

Answer (score 11):

You go to the C++ Standard Committee website:

Home: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/

And for a quick access to any published papers:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/

Answer (score 6):

In the past I've used the C++0x wiki entry, and to a lesser extent, the Informit C++ Reference. Recently, I came across a new blog that people may want to check out. It appears to have been started by a couple of committee members:

*We started this site because the community at large seems especially hungry—right now—to know more about, and to be more involved in, what's happening on the cutting edge of C++. We're going to be writing articles on C++0x and advanced C++03.
...
Thanks for visiting C++Next,
Dave Abrahams and Doug Gregor*

[http://cpp-next.com](http://cpp-next.com/)

Answer (score 3):

A lot of insiders to the standards working group discuss and post at [comp.std.c++](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/topics?pli=1) so I guess that would qualify.

Another good place is Herb Sutter [homepage](http://www.gotw.ca/) and [blog](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Trawling through my own answers, I just found this old question and realised that, while all other answers (including my own) are still valid, there is now one more important site that has been added to the list:

http://isocpp.org/

This is run by the committee themselves and has regular updates on the status of C++.  And, recursively, also points to the occasional StackOverflow post.

They also usually tweet from [@isocpp](https://twitter.com/isocpp), when an article is posted or updated, or about other C++ issues, such as videos from recent C++ conferences.

Comment: Winner . . . . .

Answer (score 1):

Since I lurk on the Boost Developers' mailing list, I tend to become informed of interesting new developments in the Standard that way.  There is usually an announcement of some kind by the folks who are both in Boost and on the committee, and this usually prompts me to look at the committee papers, and also provides for some very interesting informed discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best places to start would be e.g.:

- [C++17 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17)
- [c++ - What are the new features in C++17? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060436/what-are-the-new-features-in-c17)
- [C++20 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20)
- [C++20 - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/20)

etc.