# What are the new features in C++17?

Tags: c++, standards, c++-faq, c++17

C++17 is now feature complete, so unlikely to experience large changes. Hundreds of proposals were put forward for C++17.

Which of those features were added to C++ in C++17?

When using a C++ compiler that supports "C++1z", which of those features are going to be available when the compiler updates to C++17?

Comment: Full list of features as per Clang: [library](http://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html), [core language](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx17).

Comment: this blog bost has a nice summary: http://www.bfilipek.com/2017/01/cpp17features.html

Comment: See the official [Changes between C++14 and C++17 DIS (P0636r0)](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html) document for a list of major changes from C++14 to C++17.

Comment: @RaghavNavada Great!  Is the C++20 section being maintained?  There's [#53](https://github.com/AnthonyCalandra/modern-cpp-features/issues/53), but it's closed ...

Comment: Everything in this site https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp is marked with version required.

Answer (score 1331, accepted):

## Language features:

### Templates and Generic Code

- [Template argument deduction for class templates](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r3.html)

  - Like how functions deduce template arguments, now constructors can deduce the template arguments of the class
  - http://wg21.link/p0433r2 http://wg21.link/p0620r0 http://wg21.link/p0512r0
- [`template <auto>`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r2.html)

  - Represents a value of any (non-type template argument) type.
- [Non-type template arguments fixes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4268.html)
- [`template<template<class...>typename bob> struct foo {}`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4051.html)
- [( Folding + ... + expressions )](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4295.html)  and [Revisions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0036r0.pdf)
- [`auto x{8};` is an `int`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html)
- [modernizing `using` with `...` and lists](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0195r1.html)

### Lambda

- [constexpr lambdas](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0170r1.pdf)

  - Lambdas are implicitly constexpr if they qualify
- [Capturing `*this` in lambdas](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0018r3.html)

  - `[*this]{ std::cout << could << " be " << useful << '\n'; }`

### Attributes

- [`[[fallthrough]]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0188r1.pdf), [`[[nodiscard]]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0189r1.pdf), [`[[maybe_unused]]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0212r1.pdf) attributes
- [`[[attributes]]` on `namespace`s and `enum { erator[[s]] }`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4266.html)
- [`using` in attributes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0028r4.html) to avoid having to repeat an attribute namespace.
- Compilers are now [required to ignore non-standard attributes they don't recognize](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0283r2.html).

  - The C++14 wording allowed compilers to reject unknown scoped attributes.

### Syntax cleanup

- [Inline variables](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0386r2.pdf)

  - Like inline functions
  - Compiler picks where the instance is instantiated
  - [Deprecate static constexpr redeclaration](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0386r2.pdf), now implicitly inline.
- [`namespace A::B`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4230.html)
- Simple [`static_assert(expression);`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3928.pdf) with no string
- [no `throw` unless `throw()`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0003r4.html), and `throw()` is `noexcept(true)`.

### Cleaner multi-return and flow control

- [Structured bindings](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0217r3.html)

  - Basically, first-class `std::tie` with `auto`
  - Example:

    - `const auto [it, inserted] = map.insert( {"foo", bar} );`
    - Creates variables `it` and `inserted` with deduced type from the `pair` that `map::insert` returns.
  - Works with tuple/pair-likes & `std::array`s and relatively flat structs
  - Actually named [structured bindings](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0615r0.html) in standard
- [`if (init; condition)` and `switch (init; condition)`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0305r1.html)

  - `if (const auto [it, inserted] = map.insert( {"foo", bar} ); inserted)`
  - Extends the `if(decl)` to cases where `decl` isn't convertible-to-bool sensibly.
- [Generalizing range-based for loops](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0184r0.html)

  - Appears to be mostly support for sentinels, or end iterators that are not the same type as begin iterators, which helps with null-terminated loops and the like.
- [if constexpr](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0292r2.html)

  - Much requested feature to simplify almost-generic code.

### Misc

- [Hexadecimal float point literals](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0245r1.html)
- [Dynamic memory allocation for over-aligned data](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0035r4.html)
- [Guaranteed copy elision](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0135r1.html)

  - Finally!
  - Not in all cases, but distinguishes syntax where you are "just creating something" that was called elision, from "genuine elision".
- [Fixed order-of-evaluation for (some) expressions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf) with some [modifications](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0400r0.html)

  - Not including function arguments, but function argument evaluation interleaving now banned
  - Makes a bunch of broken code work mostly, and makes `.then` on future work.
- [Direct list-initialization of enums](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0138r2.pdf)
- Forward progress guarantees (FPG) (also, [FPGs for parallel algorithms](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0299r0.html))

  - I think this is saying "the implementation may not stall threads forever"?
- [`u8'U', u8'T', u8'F', u8'8'`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4267.html) character literals (string already existed)
- ["noexcept" in the type system](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0012r1.html)
- [`__has_include`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0061r1.html)

  - Test if a header file include would be an error
  - makes migrating from experimental to std almost seamless
- [Arrays of pointer conversion fixes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4261.html)
- [inherited constructors](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0136r1.html) fixes to some corner cases (see [P0136R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0136r0.html) for examples of behavior changes)
- [aggregate initialization with inheritance](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0017r0.html).
- [`std::launder`, type punning, etc](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0137r1.html)

## Library additions:

### Data types

- [`std::variant<Ts...>`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0088r3.html)

  - Almost-always non-empty last I checked?
  - Tagged union type
  - {awesome|useful}
- [`std::optional`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4480.html#optional)

  - Maybe holds one of something
  - Ridiculously useful
- [`std::any`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4480.html#any)

  - Holds one of anything (that is copyable)
- [`std::string_view`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4480.html#string.view)

  - `std::string` like reference-to-character-array or substring
  - Never take a `string const&` again.  Also can make parsing a bajillion times faster.
  - [`"hello world"sv`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0403r0.html)
  - [constexpr `char_traits`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0426r0.html)
- [`std::byte`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0298r3.pdf) off more than they could chew.

  - Neither an integer nor a character, just data

### Invoke stuff

- [`std::invoke`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4169.html)

  - Call any callable (function pointer, function, member pointer) with one syntax.  From the standard INVOKE concept.
- [`std::apply`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0220r1.html)

  - Takes a function-like and a tuple, and unpacks the tuple into the call.
- [`std::make_from_tuple`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0209r2.pdf), `std::apply` applied to object construction
- `is_invocable`, `is_invocable_r`, `invoke_result`

  - http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0077r2.html
  - http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0604r0.html
  - Deprecates `result_of`
  - `is_invocable<Foo(Args...), R>` is "can you call `Foo` with `Args...` and get something compatible with `R`", where `R=void` is default.
  - `invoke_result<Foo, Args...>` is `std::result_of_t<Foo(Args...)>` but apparently less confusing?

### [File System TS v1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0218r0.html)

- [`[class.path]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0218r0.html#class-path)
- [`[class.filesystem.error]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0218r0.html#Class-filesystem_error)
- [`[class.file_status]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0218r0.html#file_status)
- [`[class.directory_entry]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0218r0.html#Class-directory_entry)
- [`[class.directory_iterator]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0218r0.html#Class-directory_iterator) and [`[class.recursive_directory_iterator]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0218r0.html#class.rec.dir.itr)
- [`[fs.ops.funcs]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0218r0.html#Operational-functions)
- [`fstream`s can be opened with `path`s, as well as with `const path::value_type*` strings.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0610r0.html#2676)

### [New algorithms](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0024r2.html)

- `for_each_n`
- `reduce`
- `transform_reduce`
- `exclusive_scan`
- `inclusive_scan`
- `transform_exclusive_scan`
- `transform_inclusive_scan`
- Added for threading purposes, exposed even if you aren't using them threaded

### Threading

- [`std::shared_mutex`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4508.html)

  - Untimed, which can be more efficient if you don't need it.
- `atomic<T>`[`::is_always_lockfree`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0152r1.html)
- [`scoped_lock<Mutexes...>`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0156r2.html)

  - Saves some `std::lock` pain when locking more than one mutex at a time.
- [Parallelism TS v1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/paper/2014/n4071.htm)

  - The linked paper from 2014, may be out of date
  - Parallel versions of `std` algorithms, and related machinery
- [hardware_*_interference_size](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0154r0.html)

### (parts of) [Library Fundamentals TS v1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0220r1.html) not covered above or below

- [`[func.searchers]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4480.html#func.searchers) and [`[alg.search]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4480.html#alg.search)

  - A searching algorithm and techniques
- [`[pmr]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0220r1.html)

  - Polymorphic allocator, like `std::function` for allocators
  - And some [standard memory resources to go with it](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4480.html#memory.resource.pool).
  - http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0358r1.html
- [`std::sample`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4480.html#alg.random.sample), sampling from a range?

### Container Improvements

- [`try_emplace`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4279.html) and [`insert_or_assign`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4279.html)

  - gives better guarantees in some cases where spurious move/copy would be bad
- [Splicing for `map<>`, `unordered_map<>`, `set<>`, and `unordered_set<>`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0083r3.pdf)

  - Move nodes between containers cheaply.
  - Merge whole containers cheaply.
- non-const [`.data()`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0272r1.html) for string.
- non-member [`std::size`, `std::empty`, `std::data`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4280.pdf)

  - like `std::begin`/`end`
- [Minimal incomplete type support in containers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4510.html)
- [Contiguous iterator "concept"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4284.html)
- [`constexpr` iterators](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0031r0.html)
- The `emplace` family of functions [now returns a reference to the created object](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0084r2.pdf).

### Smart pointer changes

- [`unique_ptr<T[]>` fixes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4089.pdf) and other [`unique_ptr`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4366.html) tweaks.
- [`weak_from_this`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0033r1.html) and some fixed to shared from this

### Other `std` datatype improvements:

- [`{}` construction of `std::tuple` and other improvements](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4387)
- [TriviallyCopyable reference_wrapper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4277.html), can be performance boost

### Misc

- C++17 library is based on [C11 instead of C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0063r2.html)
- Reserved `std[0-9]+` for [future standard libraries](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0180r1.html)
- [`destroy(_at|_n)`, `uninitialized_move(_n)`, `uninitialized_value_construct(_n)`, `uninitialized_default_construct(_n)`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0040r2.html)

  - utility code already in most `std` implementations exposed
- [Special math functions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0226r1.pdf)

  - scientists may like them
- [`std::clamp()`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0025r0.html)

  - `std::clamp( a, b, c ) == std::max( b, std::min( a, c ) )` roughly
- [`gcd` and `lcm`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0295r0.pdf)
- [`std::uncaught_exceptions`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4259.pdf)

  - Required if you want to only throw if safe from destructors
- [`std::as_const`](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0007r1.html)
- [`std::bool_constant`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4389.html)
- [A whole bunch of `_v` template variables](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0006r0.html)
- [`std::void_t<T>`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3911.pdf)

  - Surprisingly useful when writing templates
- [`std::owner_less<void>`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0074r0.html)

  - like `std::less<void>`, but for smart pointers to sort based on contents
- [`std::chrono` polish](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0092r1.html)
- [`std::conjunction`, `std::disjunction`, `std::negation`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0013r1.html) exposed
- [`std::not_fn`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0005r4.html#6.10)

  - http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0358r1.html
- [Rules for noexcept within `std`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4258.pdf)
- [std::is_contiguous_layout](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0258r1.html), useful for efficient hashing
- [std::to_chars/std::from_chars](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0067r5.html), high performance, locale agnostic number conversion; finally a way to serialize/deserialize to human readable formats (JSON & co)
- <s>[std::default_order](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0181r1.html), indirection over `std::less`.</s> ([breaks ABI of some compilers](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/56zkbx/c1417_features_and_stl_fixes_in_vs_15_preview_5/d8npapy/) due to name mangling, removed.)
- [`memory_order_consume`](http://wg21.link/p0371r1), added language to prefer use of `memory_order_acquire`

### Traits

- [swap](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0185r1.html)
- [is_aggregate](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2911)
- [has_unique_object_representations](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0258r2.html)

### Deprecated

- [Some C libraries](http://wg21.link/p0063r3),
- [`<codecvt>`](http://wg21.link/p0618r0)
- [`result_of`](http://wg21.link/p0604r0), replaced with `invoke_result`
- [`shared_ptr::unique`](http://wg21.link/p0521r0), it isn't very threadsafe

[Isocpp.org has](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html) has an independent list of changes since C++14; it has been partly pillaged.

Naturally TS work continues in parallel, so there are some TS that are not-quite-ripe that will have to wait for the next iteration.  The target for the next iteration is C++20 as previously planned, not C++19 as some rumors implied.  C++1O has been avoided.

Initial list taken from [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/48zp05/what_we_added_to_the_c17_working_draft/) and [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/4pmlpz/what_the_iso_c_committee_added_to_the_c17_working/), with links added via googling or from the above isocpp.org page.

Additional entries pillaged from [SD-6](https://isocpp.org/std/standing-documents/sd-6-sg10-feature-test-recommendations) feature-test list.

[clang's feature list](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx17) and [library feature list](http://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html) are next to be pillaged.  This doesn't seem to be reliable, as it is C++1z, not C++17.

[these slides](https://codeplay.com/public/uploaded/filehost/0cbdaf_c++17post-oulu2016.pdf) had some features missing elsewhere.

While "what was removed" was not asked, here is a short list of a few things ((mostly?) previous deprecated) that are removed in C++17 from C++:

## Removed:

- [`register`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0001r1.html#6.10), keyword reserved for future use
- [`bool b; ++b;`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0002r1.html)
- [trigraphs](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4086.html)

  - if you still need them, they are now part of your source file encoding, not part of language
- [ios aliases](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0004r1.html)
- [auto_ptr, old `<functional>` stuff, `random_shuffle`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4190.htm)
- [allocators in `std::function`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0302r1.html)

There were rewordings.  I am unsure if these have any impact on code, or if they are just cleanups in the standard:

## Papers not yet integrated into above:

- [P0505R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0505r0.html) (constexpr chrono)
- [P0418R2](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0418r2.html) (atomic tweaks)
- [P0512R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0512r0.pdf) (template argument deduction tweaks)
- [P0490R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0490r0.html) (structured binding tweaks)
- [P0513R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0513r0.pdf) (changes to `std::hash`)
- [P0502R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0502r0.html) (parallel exceptions)
- [P0509R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0509r1.pdf) (updating restrictions on exception handling)
- [P0012R1](http://wg21.link/p0012r1) (make exception specifications be part of the type system)
- [P0510R0](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0510r0.html) (restrictions on variants)
- [P0504R0](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0504r0.html) (tags for optional/variant/any)
- [P0497R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0497r0.html) (shared ptr tweaks)
- [P0508R0](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0508r0.html) (structured bindings node handles)
- [P0521R0](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0521r0.html) (shared pointer use count and unique changes?)

## Spec changes:

- [exception specs and throw expressions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4285.html)

## Further reference:

- [papers grouped by year; not all accepted](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/)
- https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html

  - Should be updated to "Modifications to existing features" here.

Comment: Um, `memory_order_consume` does not seem to be officially deprecated.  It is just discouraged in the note.  Maybe it makes sense to mention this (with a trailing parenthesis, for example)?