# What is the expected relation of C++ modules and dynamic linkage?

Tags: c++, c++-modules

The C++ modules TS provides an excellent facility for eliminating the preprocessor, improving compile times, and generally supporting much more robust, modular, code development in C++, for non-template code at least.

The underlying machinery provides control over import and export of symbols in ordinary programs.

However, there is a *major* problem developing libraries for two kinds of dynamic loading: startup time loading, and run time loading. This problem involves the exporting of symbols from the library, which is often discussed in terms of visibility.

Generally, not all the extern symbols of the translation units used to construct a dynamic link library should be made visible to the user. In addition, with run time loading, especially with a plugin concept, the same symbol must be exported from many concurrently loaded libraries.

On Windows the use of language extensions

```
 __declspec(dllexport)
 __declspec(dllimport)
```

attached in source code as attributes of symbols, and more recently on gcc and clang systems on unix platforms, the use of

```
__attribute__((visibility("default")))
__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
```

are intended to support the provision and use of symbols intended to be made public by the library. Using these is complicated and messy: on Windows macros must be used to export the symbols whilst compiling the library, but import them when using it. On the unix platforms, the visibility must be set to default to both export and import the symbols, the compiler deciding itself, based on whether a definition is found or not: the compiler must be invoked with

```
-fvisibility=hidden
```

switch. The export/import attributes are not required for static linkage, and probably should be macro'd out to an empty string. Making code and fiddling the build system so that this all works, especially considering that #includes must have the correct symbol visibility set during compilation of library translation units is very hard, the file structure required in repositories is a mess, the source code is littered with macros, and in general .. the whole thing is a disaster. Almost all open source repositories FAIL to correctly export symbols for dynamic linkage, and most programmers have no idea that dynamic library code structure (using two level namespaces) is quite different to static linkage.

An example of how to do it (hopefully correctly) can be seen here:

https://github.com/calccrypto/uint256_t

This repository used to have 2 headers and 2 implementation files, the user of the built library would see 2 headers. There are now 7 headers and 2 implementation files and the user of the built library will see 5 header files (3 with extension `include` to indicate they're not to be directly included).

So after that long winded explanation, the question is: will the final C++ modules specification help to solve problems with export and import of symbols for dynamic linkage? Can we expect to be able to develop for shared libraries without polluting our code with vendor specific extensions and macros?

Comment: Probably not, c++ doesn't much about how code is linked and knows nothing about static or dynamic linking

Comment: The compiler vendors, who have reps on WG21, know lots about it.

Comment: Yes I'm not suggesting that the people writing the c++ standards dont understand linking practices I'm just saying that how code is linked together is outside the scope of the c++ language. c++ is designed to be portable, if they start adding specifications of linking the language will be less portable as some platforms won't be able to implement those linking patterns.

Comment: I don't agree. How code is linked together has, historically, always been a *key* part of C++. Recall C++ invented "mangled names". It invented various new kinds of linkage (such as vague linkage) to support templates. The abstract machine of C++ was extended to include threads, and the abstract machine can be extended to support libraries. The module TS specifically deals with symbol linkage. The Standard talks about the One Definition Rule which is a linkage issue. C++ invented inline functions, a linkage issue. So C++ can definitely be extended so the abstract machine transcends programs.

Comment: I would say, on the contrary, the C++ committee MUST address dynamic linkage. It has to change the abstract machine so the "code" of a program can vary with time because that is the reality of the modern world. It HAS to address the specification of what is exported from a library, just as the existing Standard addresses what is exported from a translation unit. The problem you mention regarding portability is *precisely* the reason the abstract machinery must be standardised. Obviously, the implementation will depend on the vendor as usual.

Comment: @Yttrill: C++ *itself* doesn’t involve name mangling at all: it talks about [signatures](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#10.3) and how declarations in different translation units that share a name and signature correspond.  Name mangling is just a way of expressing such a signature as a flat-string symbol name of the sort commonly used in object files.

Comment: @Yttrill: WG21 [is considering](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0275r3.html) dynamic linking, but it’s currently just the loading process, not symbol visibility (which the language doesn’t have at all prior to modules).  Maybe there will be a standardization of modules *as* dynamic objects, but it might be bad to force them to have the same granularity.

Comment: @DavisHerring: thanks for the link! FYI a rough idea is a language extension in which a particular *wrapper module* that contains other modules can be marked as controlling visibility in a DLL. If we do that, then that module can be built as a DLL directly, and exports only the exports of the top level of the module. So syntactically a single keyword used in exactly one place should be enough, eg "library module ...." would be enough.

Comment: The real issue is that the current C++ abstract machine model CANNOT DEAL WITH DYNAMIC LINKAGE and that is definitely an issue for the ISO Standard involving significant changes to normative rules. With dynamic loading the ODR is nonsense: types (and thus vtables) MUST be present in each DLL that constructs polymorphic types. Function which are used internally in a DLL may be duplicates, for example constructors and destructors of polymorphic classes. At present the vendors cannot get exceptions and dynamic casts to work across DLL boundaries either, because they chose a broken model.

Comment: @Yttrill: The ODR is about [definitions in source](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#12) and has nothing to do with how many (shared) object files contain a function, a vtable, or anything else that isn’t part of the *language*.  That said: yes, hilarity involving things like `RTLD_LOCAL` is a pain.

Comment: @DavisHerring: I know how the Standard works. In fact I worked on the ODR myself. The issue here is not just run time loading. If you use two level namespaces (and that is the only correct way) you can load two versions of the same library safely. Now consider both throw an the same exception, which is caught several levels up. What happens? We have THREE definitions of the type now: one in each of the libraries, and one in the catching code. Clang and gcc at least used to bomb out.

Comment: @Yttrill Any update on this topic? with msvc, how can one export symbols in a module-based-dll, and then import these symbols in another executable? even with macros, the symbols always end up being exported (even in the exe)

Answer (score 11):

Modules don't help you with symbol visibility across DLL boundaries. We can check this with a quick experiment.

```
// A.ixx
export module A;

export int f() { return 1; }
```

Here we have a simple module interface file exporting one symbol `f` in the module interface of module `A` (happens to share the same name as the file base name, but this isn't necessary). Let's compile this like so:

```
cl /c /std:c++20 /interface /TP A.ixx
```

The `/c` flag avoids invoking the linker (happens automatically by default), `c++20` or later is required for module syntax to work, and the `/interface` flag lets the compiler know we are compiling a module interface unit. The `/TP` arg says "treat the source input as a C++ input" and is needed when `/interface` is specified. Finally, we have our input file.

Running the above produces an interface file `A.ifc` and an object file `A.obj`. Note that there is no import lib file or exp file you would expect if you were compiling a DLL.

Next, let's write a file that consumes this.

```
// main.cpp
import A;

int main() { return f(); }
```

To compile this into an executable, we can use the following command:

```
cl /std:c++20 main.cpp A.obj
```

The presence of the `A.obj` input there is *not optional*. Without it, we get a classic linker error of `f` being an unresolved symbol. If we run this, we'll get a `main.exe` which statically links the code in `A.obj`.

What happens if we try and compile `A.ixx` into a DLL? That is, what if we try to produce a DLL with the linker from `A.obj`? The answer you get a DLL but no import lib or exp. If you try running `link /noentry /dll A.obj /out:A.dll` you will get an `A.dll` with the expected `/disasm` section (visible via dump bin), but no export table.

```
Dump of file A.dll

File Type: DLL

  0000000180001000: B8 01 00 00 00     mov         eax,1
  0000000180001005: C3                 ret

  Summary

        1000 .rdata
        1000 .text
```

That's the disassembly in `A.dll` which we expect, but checking the exports section with `dumpbin /export A.dll` reveals nothing. The reason is of course, we didn't export the symbol!

If we change the source code of `A.ixx` to the following:

```
// A.ixx
export module A;

export __declspec(export) int f() { return 1; }
```

... we can repeat the steps (compile `A.obj`, link `A.dll`) to find that this time, the linker produces an import lib and exp file as we'd expect. Invoking `dumpbin /exports A.lib` on the import lib generated should show the `?f@@YAHXZ` symbol present.

Now, we can link `main.cpp` again `A.lib` (as opposed to `A.obj`) via `cl /std:c++20 main.cpp A.lib` to produce a valid executable, this time relying on `A.dll` for the code instead of having `f` statically embedded.

We can check that this is in fact happening as expected in WinDbg.

[image]

Note on the lower left module pane the presence of `A.dll`. Note also that in the disassembly view in the center, we are about to call `main!f`. Uh oh, not good. While this does properly resolve to the `!A` module, it does so via an extra indirection in the import address table as seen here:

[image]

This is the classic problem that happens when you forget to decorate a function or symbol with the `__declspec(dllimport)` directive. When the compiler encounters the symbol without the `dllimport` directive that it doesn't recognize, it emits a relocation entry which is expected to be resolved at link time. Along with that entry, it emits a `jmp` and an unresolved address. This is a classic problem that I won't get into here, but the upshot is that we have an extra unnecessary indirection because the symbol recognized as exported from the module `A` was expected to be statically linked.

It turns out, we can't fix this easily. If we try to add another declaration of `f` to `main.cpp` or some other translation unit, the linker will complain that it sees `f` with "inconsistent dll linkage." The only way to resolve this is to compile a second version of the `A` module interface with `dllimport` decorations (much like how headers typically have macros that expand to `dllexport` or `dllimport` depending on the TU using the header).

The moral of the story is that DLL linkage and module linkage, while not completely at odds, aren't particularly compatible either. The module `export` does not include exported symbols in the export table, needed to resolve symbols across DLL boundaries. Furthermore, putting these symbols in the export table still leaves you the trouble of an extra indirection after the implicit dynamic link is done via the import address table.

Comment: I tested this with a very simple example in VS 17.6 and it seems that this extra indirection can be removed by the optimizer nowadays. However I do not find any documentation on this. When debugging your example in a Release-optimized build I get a direct jmp to `__imp_f` and end up in `f()` without any steps in between. The same behavior can be seen when recreating the example without modules but macros and headers instead and simply omitting `__declspec(dllimport)` for the importing translation unit. Hard to tell if you can rely on this without any credible source.

Comment: I've now read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/importing-function-calls-using-declspec-dllimport?view=msvc-170) that `dllimport` can be omitted when using whole program optimization (`/GL`). [The doc for /GL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gl-whole-program-optimization?view=msvc-170) claims that it is off by default. This is partially true, the setting is off when returning to defaults but it is on in Release when creating a console app using the VS2022 templates. When I turn off `/GL`, the behavior matches what you've described in your post.

Comment: Yes, indeed GL can help alleviate the indirection at the cost of build time, but note that it isn't always possible in cases where a vendor is shipping just the dll to clients or something.

Comment: My dreams are shattered! I somehow was hoping that c++ Modules would help to get rid of all compilation details related stuff in source files including the damn export macro headers.

Comment: @Knitschi Yup, tell me about it. We are so close to having something usable but the language spec refuses to acknowledge that dynamic linkage is even a thing, so until then, we're at the mercy of toolchain providers to come up with a stop-gap solution. I'm considering this feature DoA until there's a solution though, because I depend on DLLs for a good chunk of my work.