# How to return a NULL from a templated method, without using a pointer

Tags: c++

I have some code that looks like this:

```
template <class T>
T foo(T a) {
 if (a) {
   // do somethin', returns object of type T
 } else {
   return NULL;
 }
}
```

But of course it won't compile since NULL is not of type T. Someone suggested this solution to me but I don't like it:

```
template <class T>
T* foo(T a) {
 if (a) {
   // do somethin', returns object of type T*
 } else {
   return nullptr;
 }
}
```

I am wondering how to make this function able to return a NULL value if possible without the use of a pointer?

Comment: What do you return when you don't return null?

Comment: ^ an object of type T

Comment: Is this specific to templates?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `std::optional<T>`. It's coming in C++17, but boost has one available right now. You can also find other implementations online.

Comment: Perhaps instead of trying to return a NULL-type value, you'd be better off throwing an exception?  (if the NULL is meant to represent an error condition, anyway).  Alternatively, instead of returning a value you could return a success/failure code, and write to a caller-supplied (T &) argument only in the success case.

Comment: `NULL` or `nullptr` is a pointer value (or at least is intended to be converted to a pointer value). What does it mean to return `NULL` "without using a pointer", and why would you want to? What's your objection to `return nullptr;`? What happens -- and what do you **want** to happen -- if `foo` is used with a non-pointer type, for example `foo(42)`? With `return nullptr;` it would fail to compile, which is probably exactly what should happen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C++17, you will be able to use [`std::optional<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). And you could do something like this:

```
template <class T>
std::optional<T> foo(T a) {
    if (a) {
        // do somethin', returns object of type T
        return std::make_optional(/*Anything that constructs `T`*/);
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}
```

And on the receiving end, you can test for the value being there:

```
auto my_val = foo(obj);
if(my_val){
     /* :-) ....knock yourself out! */
}
else{
     /* :-( ....we didn't find the value */
}
```

For now,

- You can use **<kbd>[Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).</kbd>**
- Or, if you are using a very recent compiler, you may be able to access it from `std::experimental::optional`.
- Or, if you do not want to use Boost and its dependencies, you can simply grab this **[tiny header](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/blob/master/optional.hpp)** (a working implementation of optional from one of the *[proposers of `optional`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3793.html)* into the C++ standard)... It's header only, so, you only need to download/copy that single header file and `#include` it.

---

Another [cool thing with C++17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0305r0.html) is that testing for the value will now be as simple as:

```
if(auto my_val = foo(obj); my_val){
     // ....knock yourself out!
}
```

---

You can see more of C++17 features here: [What are the new features in C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060436/what-are-the-new-features-in-c17)

Comment: Hi, how do I use c++17? That's exactly what I am looking for, thanks for your response.

Comment: Actually nevermind that was a silly question, I'll look into boost, thanks

Comment: @Liz, if you do not want to use Boost, you can simply grab this [tiny header](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/blob/master/optional.hpp) (a working implementation of optional)... It's header only, so, you only need to download/copy that single header file and `#include` it.

Comment: The new `if` isn't necessary for testing an optional, you can just write `if (auto opt = foo(obj))` and it will do the right thing. thanks to `optional`'s boolean conversion operator. The new syntax is only needed when the condition is more complex than "convert the declared variable to bool".

Comment: @SebastianRedl, Thanks for pointing that out!. I do that a lot too; I chose to use the new `if` because I was additionally trying to advertise C++17. (as you can also see in the very last line of my answer).

Answer (score -3):

```
template <class T>

T list<T>::getData(int i){

    if (i < iSize && i >= 0){

        return listData[i];

    } else {

        cout << "Does not exist";

    return {};

  }

}
```

//it works pretty well

Comment: I wouldn't call it 'null'. You return a default-constucted `T`.

Comment: How do you distinguish between the default-constructed result, and a `listData[i]` that ha the same value? (hint: you can't)