# How do I find out the state of a specific suggestion/paper for the next C++?

Tags: c++, tuples, iso, c++17, hash-function

Is there a list or table of what papers have a "declined", "accepted" or "under discussion" state?

I am specifically interested if there is any hope of [N3983](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3983.pdf) for the hashing of tuples being accepted for C++1z (or if its already in C++14, which I don't think).

Answer (score 3):

Such a table doesn't exist.*

In regards to N3983, the current working draft [N4606](http://wg21.link/N4606) doesn't have any of those `hash` specializations, and it wasn't part of C++14, so unless it was accepted during the standards meeting a week ago, it probably won't be part of C++17 either due to a feature-freeze.

---

*You can, however, find out which papers have been accepted by reading reports done from committee members during and after each meeting. They're published on [isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/). In particular, you can find out what has been accepted into C++17 [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060436/what-are-the-new-features-in-c17/38060437#38060437). For rejected and "under discussion" papers, you'll have to dig around a bit more.