# Relation between C++11 emulation of C++14 generalized lambda captures, and the mutable specifier

Tags: c++11, lambda, c++14

At pages 227-228 of Item 32 from Effective Modern C++, Scott Meyers presents the following chunck of code as a way to workaround the lack of [generalized lambda captures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41519450/5825294) in C++11.

```cpp
// data is in scope
auto func =
  std::bind(
      [](const std::vector<double>& x) // I've renamed it x so there's no ambiguity in my description below
      { /* usses of x */ },
      std::move(data)
  );
```

Then he makes the following comment, which I don't quite understand overall.

> By default, the `operator()` member function inside the closure class generated from a lambda is `const`. That has the effect of rendering all data members in the closure `const` within the body of the lambda. The move-constructed copy of `data` inside the bind object is not `const`, however, so to prevent that copy of `data` from being modified inside the lambda, the lambda's parameter is declared reference-to-`const`. If the lambda were declared `mutable`, `operator()` in its closure class would not be declared `const`, and it would be appropriate to omit `const` in the lambda's parameter declaration:
>
> ```cpp
> // data is in scope
> auto func =
>   std::bind(
>     [](std::vector<doubld>& x) mutable // ditto
>     { /* uses of x */ },
>     std::move(data)
>   );
> ```

I tried to break it down:

- (non-`mutable`) lambda closures have the `operator()` member function `const`,
- therefore they cannot modify captured variables;

(That lambda, however, is not capturing anything in the first place, so the following points seem unrelated to me...)

- `std::bind` copies (well, moves) `data` in a non-`const` member variable of the `func` object;
- since the lambda takes the parameter by reference (not by value, as the whole point was to emulate C++14's move-lambda captures), the programmer could modify `data` through `x` inside the body of the lambda (which could be nounintentional);
- to avoid this, the parameter is made `const&`.

So, I don't get the point of the last period *If the lambda were declared [...]*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, writing the question helped me understand I was simply losing sight of the initial motivation of that code: emulating a generalized lambda capture.

Maybe Scott Meyers also implies that it's natural that the writer of that code expects the bind object `func` to behave like the *desired lambda* as it was coded with the same specifiers as the *actual lambda stored inside `func`* (actually the text only refers to the `mutable` specifier, maybe because it's the only one worth discussing).

In other words,

- seeing a non-`mutable` lambda stored inside `func` through `std::bind`, the programmer likely expects that `func` will behave as the corresponding non-`mutable` C++14 lambda, hence the `const` of the parameter of the actual lambda stored in `func`;
- if the actual lambda is `mutable`, then the user expects `func` to behave as the corresponding `mutable` C++14 lambda, so he does not expect it to preserve the captured value unmodified, hence the lack of `const` in the second chunk of code.

Even shorter:

A non-`mutable` lambda stored inside `func` should not modify its *argument(s)*, because the corresponding desired non-`mutable` C++14 lambda would not modify its *captured variable(s)*.