# Will the C++17 standard include "std::byte"?

Tags: c++, standards, c++17

According to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0298r0.pdf:

> `std::byte` is not an integer and not a character. `std::byte` is more expressive and type-safe than `char`.

However, this feature is not included in the C++17 feature list of [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17).

My question: **Will the C++17 standard include `std::byte`?**

Comment: The list on wikipedia is far from complete.

Comment: Where can we get the complete one?

Comment: Best guess: yes.  Various sources (twitter, reddit) say it was voted in on Friday (March 4th 2017).  It had been rejected in Issaquah in November; I'm not aware of any substantial difference between.

Comment: @AProgrammer [A paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0583r0.pdf) by Gabriel Dos Rei arguing that `std::byte` is the correct name and that its inclusion into the standard shouldn't be delayed anymore. It was rejected in Issaquah because people didn't agree on the name, even though they otherwise agreed on the feature.

Comment: We should also note that [the latest committee meeting](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4632.html) ended *yesterday*, and obviously the results from that meeting are not yet published.

Comment: *Where can we get the complete one?* [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38060436)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to Chandler Carruth on the [reddit live C++17 thread](https://www.reddit.com/live/yja7subcikd4/updates/996daa8c-0074-11e7-a961-0ec1e0632fc0):

> C++17 will have a `std::byte` type to use when referring to underlying storage rather than having to use `char` or `unsigned char`!

While it's not yet reflected in the latest working draft, it seems that it was voted in in plenary in Kona. This literally happened two days ago, so give it time.

---

It is now in the latest working draft, in the [`<cstddef>` synopsis](http://eel.is/c++draft/cstddef.syn#lib:byte).

Answer (score 4):

There's currently nothing mentioned about std::byte in the C++ 17 working draft.

See: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4618.pdf

Update:
C++ 17 will contain std::byte

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/#mailing2017-03

Comment: and now N4659 is the current working draft, and N4660 is the ballot document. According to the editor's report (N4661), their actual content is the same, and they do contain std::byte.  See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/#mailing2017-03

Comment: There is also an article in heise-online: https://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/Programmiersprachen-C-17-ist-technisch-fertig-3664796.html