# What exactly does C++17 change regarding parallelism? (And where is the authoritative doc?)

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++17

Is parallelism as such a part of the C++17 changes? When I Google "c++ parallelism" (without quotes), I come across a few different docs, and I can't piece together the timeline or the definitive changes.

- There's at least one Technical Specification at open-std.org, like
  [N4578](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4578.html).
- There's [this doc](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/P0024R2.html) at the ISO CPP website.
- A fairly recent and [deep dive](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15210/pasl.html) into parallel computing in C++
  doesn't mention C++17 at all.

Where's the single source of truth? Is parallelism part of C++17 or a separate TS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could have a look at the in-depth [C++17 feature list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060436/what-are-the-new-features-in-c17). There, you will see that the Parallelism TS is part of C++17.

The single source of truth is [isocpp](http://isocpp.org). If you look at the [status](https://isocpp.org/std/status) page, you will see that Parallelism I is in a dark green color, meaning that it will be merged in the C++ Standard.

The change is that a lot (if not all) of `<algorithm>`s have another overload which takes an `ExecutionPolicy`, where you can specify that the algorithm should run in parallel. Here is a [complete list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism/existing).