# How to return a string line by line in a function?

Tags: c++

I am reading a text file which contains integers separated by a new line. Like this.

```
5006179359870233335
13649319959095080120
17557656355642819359
15239379993672357891
3900144417965865322
12715826487550005702
```

From this file, I want to access each integer in a loop and compare it with another, in order to match those two. In function `File_read()` I can print the integers. But what I want is to get it integer by integer outside the function. For example in `main` method, if there is a integer called `x`, I want to check whether `x` equals one of the integers in my text file.

```
string File_read() {
    std::ifstream my_file("H:\\Sanduni_projects\\testing\\test.txt", 
    std::ifstream::binary);
    if (my_file) {
        string line;

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
            getline(my_file, line);
            //cout << line << endl;
            return line;
        }

        if (my_file)
            std::cout << "all characters read successfully."<<endl;

        my_file.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when I was calling this function, only the first integer of the text file returns. But when I change my code replacing   return line; with //cout << line << endl; , which I have commented, I can read all integers

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of amending it with comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are, currently, just returning the first number (as a `std::string` and not a number). If you remove the `return` statement in your loop you can, of course, print each of them. Here is a slightly modified version of your `File_read` function that will return a `std::vector<unsigned long long>` that contains all the numbers. Then  you can use this vector in, e.g., your `main` function to do your processing.

```
std::vector<unsigned long long> File_read()
{
    std::vector<unsigned long long> numbers;
    std::ifstream my_file("H:\\Sanduni_projects\\testing\\test.txt"); // Text files are not 'binany', i.e., removed std::ifstream::binary
    if (my_file)
    {
        std::string line;

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            std::getline(my_file, line);
            numbers.push_back(std::stoull(line));
        }

        if (my_file)
        {
            std::cout << "all characters read successfully." << std::endl;
        }

//        my_file.close(); // Do not do this manually
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long long x = /* some number */;

    // Read all the numbers
    std::vector<unsigned long long> vl = File_read();

    // Run through all the numbers
    for (unsigned long long y : vl)
    {
        // Check if any of the numbers are equal to x
        if (x == y)
        {
            // There is a match...
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

*Update*

The numbers cannot be held by in a `long`, however `unsigned long long` is sufficient.

Comment: I have changed the code according to yours. I builds without errors. But while running it breaks giving this Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEFD0BB3DD in AdDetectionMPEG4.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x00000000002BFA90.

Comment: `long` is not enough to fit those numbers.

Comment: @SanduniWickramasinghe As @Snps has pointed out I forgot to make the type `unsigned`, so instead of `long` you should use `unsigned long long`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Jonas `unsigned long` is only guaranteed to fit 32 bits. This will still not be enough. `unsigned long long` (at least 64 bits guaranteed) is needed.

Comment: @Snps You are, strictly speaking right, but on most 64 bit architectures `long` is also 8 bytes. I Have updated the answer.

Comment: problem still exists although I made it unsigned long

Comment: @SanduniWickramasinghe Also change `std::stol` to `std::stoull`, in `numbers.push_back(std::stoull(line));`

Answer (score 1):

## Never return unconditionally inside a loop.

You are returning unconditionally from inside the loop. This causes the caller to exit the loop and return from the function during the first iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
    getline(my_file, line);
    return line; // <-- Return from function (rest of iterations unreachable). Bad.
}
```

## No need to reinvent stuff

Use the standard library to read the numbers, *e.g.*, into a container `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<unsigned long long> v{std::istream_iterator<unsigned long long>{my_file},
                                  std::istream_iterator<unsigned long long>{}};
```

Notice the value type of `unsigned long long` that is needed to fit the large numbers (you're pushing ~64 bits here).

## Find a match

Use, *e.g.*, `std::find` to find a possible match among the parsed numbers.

```
auto key = 15239379993672357891ull;

if (auto it = std::find(std::begin(v), std::end(v), key); it != std::end(v)) {
    std::cout << "Key found at line " << std::distance(std::begin(v), it) + 1 << std::endl;
}
```

Here, I'm using a [C++1z `if(init; condition)` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38060436/873025) to limit the scope of the iterator `it` to inside the if statement. It's optional of course.

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67270ce179d7f356)

Comment: Why do you `+ 1` to the distance?

Comment: Maybe you should add a note on the most vexing parse problem in case OP cannot use aggregate initialization when populating the vector.

Comment: @Jonas Because line number counts are IMHO most intuitively described as starting on line 1, not line zero.

Comment: @Jonas Hmm, most vexing parse seems to me like a problem of the past, when curly-brace initialization, sometimes called uniform initialization, is available (aggregate initialization is something else). Your comment is welcome though.

Comment: The "Never return unconditionally inside a loop" is somewhat strong, because its the desired semantic when searching. Although you could replace the search with find(_if)

Comment: @Caleth "_its the desired semantic when searching_" - then it's not unconditional, is it? `std::find` has a condition to only return _when a match is found_, or the end is reached.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<long> File_read(){
    vector<long> numbers;
    ifstream my_file("H:\\Sanduni_projects\\testing\\test.txt", 
     std::ifstream::binary);
    if (my_file) {
        string line;

        for (int i = 0; i < frames_sec; i++){
            getline(my_file, line);
            numbers.push_back(std::stol(line));
        }

        if (my_file)
            std::cout << "all characters read successfully." << endl;
        else
            std::cout << "error: only " << my_file.gcount() << " could be read" << endl;
        my_file.close();

    }
    else{
        cout << "File can not be opened" << endl;
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the someone gives the answers that works correctly, I want to share my code.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
#define MAX_SIZE 4096
class FileRead
{
public:
    FileRead(string path) :_file(path)
    {
        Reset();
    }
    void Reset()
    {
        memset(_buff, 0, MAX_SIZE);
    }
    string ReadLine()
    {
        if (!_file.is_open())
        {
            cout << "error open file" << endl;  
            return "";
        }
        if (!_file.eof())
        {
            Reset();
            _file.getline(_buff,MAX_SIZE);
            return string(_buff);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "read file finished." << endl;
            return "";
        }       
    }

private:
    ifstream _file;
    string _line;
    char _buff[MAX_SIZE];
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    FileRead fr("H:\\Sanduni_projects\\testing\\test.txt");
    string line;
    while (!(line = fr.ReadLine()).empty())
    {
        //do some compare..
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct about how return works, but there is [something](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/coroutine/coroutine/asymmetric.html) that acts how you thought return acted.

```
using string_coro = boost::coroutines::asymmetric_coroutine<std::string>

void File_read(string_coro::push_type & yield) {
    std::ifstream my_file("H:\\Sanduni_projects\\testing\\test.txt", std::ifstream::binary);
    if (my_file) {
        string line;

        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
            getline(my_file, line);
            yield (line);
        }

        if (my_file)
            std::cout << "all characters read successfully." << std::endl;

        my_file.close();
    }
}
```

Which is used like this

```
string_coro::pull_type(File_read) strings;
for (const std::string & s : strings)
    std::cout << s << endl;
```