# Are extensions for parallelism going to be available for the new C++17 Standard?

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, clang++

First of all, C++17 changes are listed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060436/what-are-the-new-features-in-c17). Today I downloaded clang to check if it was complete for C++17 (as gcc hasn't implemented everything yet), and [here](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) you can read:

> Clang 5 and later implement all the features of the C++ 2017 Draft International Standard.
>
> You can use Clang in C++17 mode with the -std=c++17 option (use -std=c++1z in Clang 4 and earlier).

Then, I assume that all features of C++17 have been added in clang 5.0, but checking all of them, I couldn't find the extensions for parallelism of stl algorithms and so on. I tried adding the header `<execution>` to test the new feature, but nothing seems to work.

I'm suspencting that this feature "maybe" won't be available, but I'm not sure because there's almost no information about it.

I think Intel implemented something in its compiler, but I'm not really into it since I use Linux.

Comment: Yes, extensions for parallelism are going to be available for the new C++17 Standard. And what really was your question?

Comment: @manni66 In the clang page, they claim that C++17 is completed for Clang 5, but it still doesn't include extensions for parallelism, which doesn't make sense since it's complete.

Comment: You still don't ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are extensions for parallelism going to be available for the new C++17 Standard?

Yes, [extensions for parallelism](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism) have been merged into the ISO C++ Standard.

---

> Clang 5 and later implement all the features of the C++ 2017 Draft International Standard.

This seems to refer only to *core language features*. You probably want to check the `libc++` and/or `libstdc++` conformance status instead.

- https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html
- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html

In the above links, [P0024](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0024r2.html) is not marked as implemented.

Comment: So by now, full C++17 is not supported, right? Okay, I probably misunderstood the point of the latest implementations. Thank you for the clarification!