# How to correctly port dynamic exceptions to C++17 from C++98

Tags: c++, exception, c++17, throw

I have to deal with very old C++ code which is including a header file containing code snippets like this one,

```
  static inline unsigned int
  EventId(unsigned long Header) throw (std::string)
  {
    if (!isTDCHeader(Header)  && !isTDCTrailer(Header)) {
      throw std::string("CAENV1x90Data::EventId - not a tdc header");
    } 
    else {
      return ((Header & EVENTID_MASK) >> EVENTID_RSHIFT);
    }
  }
```

Snippets like this cause compiling errors like the following,

```
error: ISO C++1z does not allow dynamic exception specifications
   Lost(unsigned long datum) throw (std::string)
```

I understand why this is happening, but I have no idea how to port this code to compile under C++17 with a minimal amount of "headache".

I found questions such as

- [c++1z dynamic exception specification error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284705/c1z-dynamic-exception-specification-error/48610792#48610792)
- [Are dynamic exception specifications invalid in c++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47727108/are-dynamic-exception-specifications-invalid-in-c17)

but I am not able to translate the solution to my case as I am absolutely not a C++ "aficionado" (even though I promised myself to start someday...).

Comment: `EventId(unsigned long Header) throw (std::string)` -> `EventId(unsigned long Header)`

Comment: Thanks that worked! I have no idea why exactly, but it worked. I guess the `throw std::string("bla");` part is fine then...

Comment: Long story short, C++ found the specifications useless, so got rid of them.

Comment: Yes, as the Q&A's you've linked to cover, its the exception specification (the `thow (some_type)` part after the function that was removed from C++.  You can't still throw exceptions.

Comment: What is more useful to know for an optimizer is if a function can't throw an exception, and that is why we got `noexcept` and the new way of doing exception specifications.

Comment: _Unrelated (to go further):_ If you have to rework this code, it would be a better practice to throw an exception deriving from `std::exception` instead of a `std::string` directly. It makes possible to handle exceptions through polymorphism instead (without caring about the actual type, it allows to just catch `std::exception` by reference).

Comment: Just drop it. You relay do not need `dynamic exception specifications`. AFAIK it doesn't impacts name mangling so even in case of dynamic library this should not be a problem. Only if you have empty list you translate `throw()` into `noexcept`.

Comment: You can use `noexcept(false)` if you want to *explicitly* highlight the fact that a function can potentially throw.

Comment: If you're ever given the chance to rework this code I'd suggest rewriting it so that it fails using a `std::optional` or a `std::variant` this code doesn't need to throw and exception since failure appears to be anticipated quite often. The current thought process is that exceptions really should be a non-recoverable error ideally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic exception specifications were dropped without any real replacement.

Simply remove all such specifiers, except if the argument list is empty (`throw()`), in which case it should be replaced by `noexcept`. Also, if a destructor or `operator delete`/`operator delete[]` should have anything but `throw()` as such a specifier, then replace it with `noexcept(false)`.

And don't confuse the dynamic exception specification on a function declaration with a throw-expression. Both use the keyword `throw`, but of course you should only remove the former, not the latter.

The default in C++ is that all functions (with minor exceptions like destructors since C++11) can throw any type as an exception. `noexcept` (or equivalently `noexcept(true)`) and `noexcept(false)` can be used to change that default, but it isn't possible anymore to specify types of exceptions that can be thrown explicitly.