# Why need to forward constructor parameters when inheriting from variadic arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, lambda, language-lawyer

I know the title makes exactly 0 sense, I am challenging you to edit it according to the question.
I have the following wrapper that wraps lambda expressions (inherits from them) and uses their `operator()'s` for overloading.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... F>
struct OverloadSet : public F...
{
    OverloadSet(F&&... f) : F(std::forward<F>(f))...{}
    using F::operator() ...;
};

template<typename... T>
auto overloads(T...t) {
    return OverloadSet<T...>(std::forward<T>(t)...);
}

auto s = overloads(
    [](int s) {std::cout << typeid(s).name() << " " << s << std::endl; },
    [](double d) {std::cout << typeid(d).name() << " " << d << std::endl; }
);
int main() 
{
    auto s = overloads(
        [](int s) {std::cout<<typeid(s).name()<<" " << s << std::endl; },
        [](double d) {std::cout << typeid(d).name() << " "<< d << std::endl; }
    );
    s(3);
    s(3.2);
}
```

The code is copied from C++ design patterns book (highly recommend)

And I have made my observation that the constructor params are redundant as we only need `operator()'s` of base classes.
So I made the exact example but with more modest constructor:

```
OverloadSet(F&&... f) {}
```

From this point I have problems to understand whether this program is ill formed or not because have different reaction from different compilers:

**GCC 11.2**

```
Output of x86-64 gcc 11.2 (Compiler #1)
In instantiation of 'OverloadSet<F>::OverloadSet(F&& ...) [with F = {<lambda(int)>, <lambda(double)>}]':
required from 'auto overloads(T ...) [with T = {<lambda(int)>, <lambda(double)>}]'
required from here
error: use of deleted function '<lambda(int)>::<lambda>()'
```

**Clang (latest)**

```
error: constructor for 'OverloadSet<(lambda at <source>:16:2),
 (lambda at <source>:17:2)>' must explicitly initialize the base class '(lambda at <source>:16:2)' which does not have a default constructor
            OverloadSet(F&&... f) {}// F(std::forward<F>(f))...{}
```

**MSVC2019 (with C++20 enabled)**

```
Compiles and prints:
int 3
double 3.2
```

**So the questions are:**

1. Whether the program is well formed?
2. If not, why do we need to forward arguments if we only use operator()'s of base classes?

Comment: As an aside, you know this is much simpler to write as an aggregate, right? All it takes is... not defining any constructor.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: The example https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case, because none of your functors have state. If you add state into the mix, you have to construct all of the bases.

Comment: Also, before C++20, non-capturing closure objects did not need to be default constructible, so that also made this required.

Comment: Yes, the constructor doesn't make sense in c++17, but you have to omit it completely. See a simple imoelmentation in one of my answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49028089/2805305 there's also a similar implementation on cppreference, but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambda does not have a default constructor, I guess.

It is more like this:

```cpp
class A {
  public:
    A(int a) {}
};

class B {
  public:
    B(double b) {}
};

class C : public A, public B {
  public:
    C() {} // error
};
```