# Is this nested namespace syntax standard in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces, nested

Is this standard in C++? In C#, I liked declaring nested namespaces  like this:

```
namespace A.B 
{
    class X
    {
    };
}
```

The alternative was this, which is a little uglier:

```
namespace A
{
    namespace B
    {
        class X
        {
        };
    }
}
```

In C++, I wanted to see if it had a similar feature. I ended up finding this works:

```
namespace A::B
{
    class Vector2D
    {
    }
}
```

Notice the `::`.

I'm curious if this is standard C++ or if this is a MS feature. I can't find any documentation on it. My ancient C++98 reference book doesn't mention it, so I wonder if it's an extension from Microsoft or a new feature.

Comment: **Off-topic** since asking about external resources. See some [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) site and read some C++ standard like [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

Comment: It's a new feature in C++17, [mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38060437/1848654).

Comment: I believe I found the answer here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace "namespace ns_name::name  (since C++ 17)"

Comment: Too bad Unreal only supports C++ 11 at this moment, but good to know for other projects. Thanks.

Comment: @Bob - Unreal? Isn't it a set of API's in C++ for a game engine? What does that have to do with compiler support?

Comment: Last I heard UE4 only supports C++ 11 right now. I'm not sure on the details. I'm starting to think the version is independent of Unreal given what you said.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, this is [legal C++ 17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) syntax. It is, however, not called embedded namespace, but *nested namespace*.

> `namespace` *ns_name*`::`*name*   (8) (since C++17)
>
> [...]
>
> 8) nested namespace definition: `namespace A::B::C { ... }` is equivalent to `namespace A { namespace B { namespace C { ... } } }`.